# ng-repeat only repeating once while trying to populate table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a table based on the selection of a drop down list. The user would choose 1 to 12 and that number would be the amount of rows to create in the table. Here is my code so far

```
 <body ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        <p>Blue Corner Boxer: </p> <input type="text" ng-model="nameBlue">
        <br>
        <p>Red Corner Boxer: </p> <input type="text" ng-model="nameRed">
        <br>
        <p>Number of Rounds:</p> <select ng-model="selectedRounds"><option ng-repeat="x in rounds">{{x}}</option></select>
    </div>

    <div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:center">{{nameBlue}}</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center">Round</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center">{{nameRed}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="tablerows">
                        <tr ng-repeat="x in getRoundsArray(selectedRounds) track by $index">
                           <td><select ng-options="x for x in score"></select></td>
                           <td>Score</td>
                           <td><select ng-options="x for x in score"></select></td>
                       </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>



var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);


myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
$scope.message = "AngularJS tutorial";
$scope.score = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$scope.rounds = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
$scope.selectedRounds = 0;


$scope.getRoundsArray = function(rounds){
    return new Array(rounds);
 }
});
```

No matter what number I choose in the drop down list it just adds 1 row to the table at a time for each selection I make. Instead I want 6 rows as soon as user selects 6.

Comment: Try using y and z? Anyway, What is updating your list or array?

Comment: Maybe not the answer to your question, but just a tip: you should look into ng-options instead of using ng-repeat to create all your options for your select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-architect your code slightly. 
The repeat needs to be over a scoped variable (`tableArray` in my example) that changes whenever the dropdown changes.
You also do need the `$index` in the track for it to work.

Here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TVMdpI33KnmTk5E5jotf?p=preview).

Your function

```
return new Array(rounds);
```

has changed to

```
$scope.tableArray = new Array( $scope.selectedRounds * 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.getRoundsArray = function(rounds){
    return new Array(rounds);
 }
});
```

this does not do what you think it does. You are calling it as `getRoundsArray(6)`, which creates an array with ***one*** entry, which is `6`, and ***not***, as you want, an array with six entries.

See, for example, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp.

Thus, your

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in getRoundsArray(selectedRounds) track by $index">
```

repeats for each of the ***one*** entries of that array, giving the result that you describe.

(and you don't need that `track by`)